# Facebook C# SDK on ASP.NET MVC 3, Potentially dangerous request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

The standard "Potentially dangerous request" is expected, resolve it with `[ValidateInput(false)]` or something more granular if you wish.

In my case, it happens when I make a call to `FbApp.Session`. I have a BaseController that all Controllers derive from. In there is an `override OnActionExecuting` call. Pretty common scenario.

Inside of OnActionExecuting, I use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) to manage my use membership. Using `if (FbApp.Session != null)` is how I check if the user is authenticated.

While running the debugger, it points to the call to `FbApp.Session` as the source of the exception stating "A potentially dangerous request...", due to HTML in one of the posted request vars - even though the actual action I'm posting to has `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute.

What is going on inside the Facebook C# SDK that would cause this behavior? How can this be resolved?

**Edit:** looks like this could be [a bug in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1632006.aspx?ASP.NET+MVC3+RC2+bug+binding+from+request+parameters+to+method+parameters) (I haven't upgraded to full release yet). I'll upgrade and report my findings.

Comment: Which sdk are you using?

Comment: The Facebook C# SDK by Nathan Totten (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: If you have a stack trace available, please provide it.  Generally this means that somebody (maybe the SDK) tried calling Request.Form directly.  Remember, the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute only affects model binding unless you combine it with <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />, which turns it off everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Levi. When I get back to my workstation I'll get the stack trace. Maybe I'll just add '<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />' and check data manually.

Comment: Let me know how it works after you upgrade to MVC3 RTM. I can't think of anything inside the sdk that would cause that.

Comment: I upgraded to MVC3 RTM, that didn't resolve it. I added <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> and that stops it... albeit globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, make sure you're on ASP.NET MVC3 RTM, and have `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in web.config.